# Nondimensionalization of Coupled ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So what I'm messing around with are these two coupled ODES:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\gamma x\left(1 - \frac{\alpha x+\beta y}{N}\right)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\theta y\left(1 - \frac{\alpha x+\beta y}{N}\right)$$

where $\gamma , \alpha , \beta , \theta \space and \space N$ are constants

As an exercise I  try to nondimensionalize them by setting $$x =c_1X, \space y=c_2Y \space and \space t = c_3\tau$$

I get

$$\frac{dX}{d\tau}= \gamma c_3X - \frac{\gamma c_3c_1\alpha X^2+\beta c_3c_2\gamma XY}{N}$$

$$\frac{dY}{d\tau} = \theta c_3Y - \frac{\theta c_3c_2\beta Y^2  + \alpha c_2c_3\theta XY}{N}) $$

At this particular critical point in time, I set 
$$c_3 = 1/\gamma,\space\gamma c_3c_1\alpha = 1, \space\beta c_3c_2\gamma = 1 $$

where I will finally get
$$\frac{dX}{d\tau}=X\left(1 - \frac{X+Y}{N}\right)$$

$$\frac{dY}{d\tau}=\kappa Y\left(1 - \frac{X+Y}{N}\right)$$

Now I'm just curious, if I'm doing it right, and if there are other methods to nondimensionalize it.

Comment: Why you cannot just define $X=\alpha x$, $Y=\beta Y$ $\tau=t\gamma$ and omit all these intermediate $c1,c2,c3$

Comment: Thanks, it turns out it made the work much simpler

Comment: You could rescale $X$ and $Y$ yet again to get rid of the $N$.